# How do I parse json string that contains list with gson?

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

How do I parse this particular json string with Gson in Java?

```
{"orders":[{"oid":"347","status":"1"},{"oid":"348","status":"1"}],"a":14.15,"b":0}
```

What is problematic is the orders list.

I suppose one has to use a "type token" parameter to Gson.parse(json,type-toke), but it is not clear to me how this can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create java types that it can be mapped to.  So, you would have something like this.

```
public class Result {
    private List<Order> orders;
    private Number a;
    private Number b;

    // getter and setter for orders, a, and b
}

public class Order {
    private Number oid;
    private Number status;
    // getter and setter for oid and status
}
```

Then you can just do the parsing with something like

```
Result result = gson.fromJson( yourSring, Result.class );
```

caveat, this is uncompiled, untested code, but should get you close.

Comment: This works. I thought it would involve something more complicated.

Comment: Will this also maitain the order of list?? 
means if I'll do `orders.get(0).getOid()' then will it return 347??

Comment: yes, the order of the items in the list will be the same as the order they appear in the JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you can use json-path in java, see document. It's simple and clever.
http://code.google.com/p/json-path/

Comment: Please explain a little. only giving reference of any external link is not taken as a good answer.